# QRY works perfect for individual results, but gives bad data for large group results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL project that takes existing agent schedule data and applies exclusions based on a separate table.
I'm using UNIONs to split the schedule data out based on a number of queries.

The query runs 100% accurate when I run an agent individually, but if I pull the same data as a population rows disappear.

I'm very perplexed by this.  I've checked my ORDER BY clauses are consistent.  I do not understand why the query is different between individual Agent records and population Agent records.

I can upload the code but it's a 9 page item, seems a bit much to upload on this.  Please let me know if you'd like me to upload the query.

I have verified my ORDER BY statements are cohesive.

I expect to see the existing Agent Schedule data sliced/compiled (using a number of queries).  The subqueries identify whether it is a complete/partial/not exclusion.

Comment: If you try to answer this question, [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), odds are good that you'll also answer your own question. Lots of times, trying to get to a working, small code sample uncovers the underlying issue

Comment: I am using Schedule Data LEFT JOIN to my Exclusion data as my base, and then adding that data as a LEFT JOIN to Schedule data a second time to ensure I account for all records.

Comment: With no sample code we have no idea what you are dealing with.

Comment: It's 9pgs of code